# Remove focus from a Delphi component

Tags: delphi, components, mouseevent

I have a `TEdit` in a Delphi VCL form app.  After I finish editing in the `TEdit` component, the caret and focus remain on this component until I click on another control.  I can change the focus to another edit component by clicking there, but I want to remove the focus from any component (hide the caret and editing activity).   What do I have to do to properly remove the focus from any component?

As a related issue, if the solution should be placed in the form's `OnClick` event,  I have a large number of frames on the form with their own `OnClick` events and I want to avoid adding code to each one for this issue.

Comment: You didn't say what "After I finish editing" actually means. Do you click a button? Press Enter?

Comment: Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2264645/12763954) out.